# Flask view takes int argument, throws error if someone enters a string

Tags: flask, account

Here's the code

```
@app.route('/account/<user_id>', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def user(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id = user_id).first()
 ...
return render_template('template.html')
```

If someone manually enters
    htp://localhost/user/aaa for example, it throws an error. How can I check that the user id is an int before it throws an error? On the production server, it will probably throw a server error, but it would be better just to throw a 403 forbidden error.

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the error stacktrace ?

Comment: @codegeek

First post on here, it says that the stacktrace is too long. How would I copy the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `int` converter:

```
@app.route('/account/<int:user_id>', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def user(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id = user_id).first()
    ...
    return render_template('template.html')
```

Also see documentation: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#builtin-converters.